# Why is This Saying No Known Conversion from "nullptr_t to const"?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

Originally the project compiled and ran fine. Then without tinkering with the `setuptab.h|.cpp` files, I tried to avoid creating a new instance of the `setuptab` and so I tried just passing it over.

### The Error

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'Ps::MainView'
        m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr), m_setupTab)
                        ^        ~~~~~~~

Candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'nullptr_t' to 'const Ps::MainView' for 1st argument
    class MainView : public QMainWindow
          ^
```

It's a small project, I have the following files:

```
main.cpp
startup.h|.cpp

View/mainview.h|.cpp
View/setuptab.h|.cpp
```

### My `main.cpp` is simply:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "startup.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Ps::Startup start_up;
    start_up.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

### `Startup.cpp`

```
#include "startup.h"
#include "View/mainview.h"
#include "View/setuptab.h"

namespace Ps
{
    Startup::Startup() :
        QObject(nullptr),
        m_setupTab(*new SetupTab(nullptr)),
        m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr), m_setupTab) //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR COMES FROM

    {
    }

    void Startup::show() const{
        m_mainView.show();

    }
}
```

**Then the following header files were created, if you want the corresponding .cpp, just let me know.**

### `startup.h:`

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

namespace Ps{

    class MainView;
    class SetupTab;

    class Startup final : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Startup();
        void show() const ;

    private:
        SetupTab& m_setupTab;
        MainView& m_mainView;

        explicit Startup(const Startup& rhs) = delete;
        Startup& operator= (const Startup& rhs) = delete;
    };
}
```

### `mainview.h`

```
#ifndef MAINVIEW_H
#define MAINVIEW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainView;
}

namespace Ps {

    class SetupTab;

    class MainView : public QMainWindow //corresponding candidate error
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainView(QWidget *parent, Ps::SetupTab &setup);
        ~MainView();

    private:
        SetupTab& m_setupTab;
        Ui::MainView *ui;
    };
}

#endif // MAINVIEW_H
```

### setuptab.h

```
#ifndef SETUPTAB_H
#define SETUPTAB_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
    class SetupTab;
}

namespace Ps {
    class SetupTab : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit SetupTab(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~SetupTab();

    private:
        Ui::SetupTab *ui;
    };
}

#endif // SETUPTAB_H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MainView` constructor takes two arguments:

```
explicit MainView(QWidget *parent, Ps::SetupTab &setup);
```

You're calling it with just one:

```
m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr), m_setupTab)
                         ^^^^^^^
```

It looks like you've simply got the parentheses in the wrong place:

```
m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr, m_setupTab))
```

The error message is given because the only constructor with a single argument is the implicitly declared copy constructor, so the compiler suggests that as the most likely candidate.

Comment: What, no mention of the resource leak and the misuse of `new`?

Comment: @Yakk: I'm not familiar enough with Qt's object ownership model to say whether this is going to cause a leak. I think it won't, as long as the object is assigned a parent at some point.

Comment: Ah, it is being stored in a reference: at first glance I thought the OP was copying from `new`.  So only an abomination, it might not be a leak.

Comment: It compiled and worked. If it's a terrible abomination, what improvement would you make? =P

Comment: @fiz don't store `new`'d pointers in references.  Create pointers in a context with clear ownership?  Mayhap Qt mainviews are implicilty owned by the framework?